# Flutter select text on long press

Tags: flutter, text, widget

I'm pretty new to flutter and need to full fill one use case:
I have one text widget.
Example: Hello there, Good morning.
In this text widget, when user long presses on any word say "Good", how to detect those?

I need to log into console that "user selected "Good" from this text".

How to do that in flutter text widget?

Comment: Use `SelectableText`

Comment: Ya , how to get the text selected by users from SelectableText

Comment: When user selects say `Good` there is an option callback in `SelectableText` you can simply use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SelectableText()` widget

```
Container(
    child: SelectableText(
        "Hello good morning"
    )
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But here how we can get the selected text in flutter.? In this case you have selected "good", but in the back end how to get the text selected by user?

Comment: use clipboardevents to get what was copied and save it to back end.